# How do I get inter-service networking working with docker-compose behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: proxy, docker-compose

I need to run docker-compose networks behind a corporate proxy, but because of the proxy, access between services often ends up getting routed through the proxy, which obviously doesn't know about them.

For example, this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
   webserver:
     image: nginx
   webtest:
     image: alpine
     command: sh -c "sleep 1 && wget -O - http://webserver"
```

Fails because `wget` is asking the corporate proxy about `webserver` and it doesn't get pointed at the service I created:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1   ... done
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1 ... done
Attaching to dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1, dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1
webtest_1    | Connecting to proxy.blah.blah.blah:8080 (xx.xx.xx.xx:8080)
webtest_1    | wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 307 Temporarily Moved for Domain Name Expansion
```

If I change the command to a tools that don't use proxies like `ping`, it works fine:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1 ... done
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1   ... done
Attaching to dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1, dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1
webtest_1    | PING webserver (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
webtest_1    | 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
webtest_1    | 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms
webtest_1    | 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
webtest_1    | 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
webtest_1    | 
webtest_1    | --- webserver ping statistics ---
webtest_1    | 4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
webtest_1    | round-trip min/avg/max = 0.072/0.083/0.095 ms
dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1 exited with code 0
```

So, what's the best way to set this up so that proxies are ignored when trying to access docker-compose launched services? Is there someway for docker-compose to automatically add services to the `no_proxy` environment variable it creates from `~/.docker/config.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have to date, is that the `no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY` environment variables need to be updated on each service to include the services that it wants to access. But this is quite bulky and it would be great if there was another way:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
   webserver:
     image: nginx
   webtest:
     image: cirrusci/wget # docker image with prebuild GNU wget                                                                                                
     command: sh -c "sleep 1 && wget -O - http://webserver"
     environment:
       - no_proxy=webserver,${no_proxy}
       - NO_PROXY=webserver,${NO_PROXY}
```

Unfortunately, the busybox version of `wget` that comes with alpine doesn't seem to support `no_proxy`/`NO_PROXY`, so I had to use an image that has GNU wget ready to go. But it does work:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1 ... done
Starting dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1   ... done
Attaching to dgx-docker-network-test_webserver_1, dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1
webtest_1    | --2019-01-21 02:45:07--  http://webserver/
webtest_1    | Resolving webserver... 172.18.0.2
webtest_1    | Connecting to webserver|172.18.0.2|:80... connected.
webtest_1    | HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
webtest_1    | Length: 612 [text/html]
webtest_1    | Saving to: 'STDOUT'
webtest_1    | 
webtest_1    |      0K                                        <!DOCTYPE html>
webtest_1    | <html>
webtest_1    | <head>
webtest_1    | <title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
webtest_1    | <style>
webtest_1    |     body {
webtest_1    |         width: 35em;
webtest_1    |         margin: 0 auto;
webtest_1    |         font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
webtest_1    |     }
webtest_1    | </style>
webtest_1    | </head>
webtest_1    | <body>
webtest_1    | <h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
webtest_1    | <p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
webtest_1    | working. Further configuration is required.</p>
webtest_1    | 
webtest_1    | <p>For online documentation and support please refer to
webtest_1    | <a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
webtest_1    | Commercial support is available at
webtest_1    | <a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>
webtest_1    | 
webtest_1    | <p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
webtest_1    | </body>
webtest_1    | </html>
webserver_1  | 172.18.0.3 - - [21/Jan/2019:02:45:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Wget/1.19.5 (linux-musl)" "-"
webtest_1    |                100% 62.8M=0s
webtest_1    | 
webtest_1    | 2019-01-21 02:45:07 (62.8 MB/s) - written to stdout [612/612]
webtest_1    | 
dgx-docker-network-test_webtest_1 exited with code 0
```

I'm not super happy with this solution because:

1. I have to repeat it for both `no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY`.
2. I have to either list all services in `no_proxy`/`NO_PROXY` on all services, or go
   through my `docker-compose.yml` and custom design the list for each service based on what I want to access
3. I'm not including anything about `no_proxy`/`NO_PROXY` from `~/.docker/config.json`, which could be a problem in some setups.

Given that `docker` is already parsing `no_proxy`/`NO_PROXY` from `~/.docker/config.json`, it would be great if `docker-compose` could build on that to handle this automatically in some fashion.